# How should I handle javascript-files in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I use express.js to create a mostly front-end application. I want to run some javascript but can't find a good way to handle it in the docs. Is there any solutions out there to merge, compress, gzip and primarily include javascripts? In middleman for rubyonrails you can do this to include files:

```
//= require vendor/_slideout18
//= require vendor/_flickity
//= require vendor/_sprint
//= require fastclick
//= require reqwest
//= require js.cookie
//= require utils/utils
//= require modules/state
//= require modules/navigation_button
```

Using koala-app, you can do this to prepend js-files to other js-files:

```
// @koala-prepend "modules/alts.js"
// @koala-prepend "modules/expandable.js"
// @koala-prepend "modules/otherQuestions.js"
```

Is there something similar in node? I would prefer if this didn't require an external application, like grunt.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try it with [Express Static Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and [Express Compress Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.compress());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Here is one sample [link](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content)

---

For merge js files, here is one module named [`merge-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-js) which is used in one middleware of Express to add merge multiple js files according to their dependencies on each other and produce a combined js file by uglifying the result.

```
app.use(require("merge-js").middleware({ 
    src: __dirname + "/assets", 
    dest: __dirname + "/public" 
}));
```

In this case, merge looks up for the js files in /assets dir and compiles them to /public dir.

Comment: This sounds good, do you know what order the files will be merged in, with js, it's kind of important ;)

Comment: from the article compress seems to only gzip files, not merge them.

Comment: @Himmators, sorry for previous misunderstanding. Maybe the `merge-js` could be used in express as merge js middleware.